# Jquery Function is saying not defined when running a php script

Tags: php, jquery, sql, ajax

I am essentially making it so when you click on a button to "vote up"

at the moment i have

**clients.php**

```
<?php

$clientInfo = "SELECT * FROM Clients ORDER BY Client ASC";
$stmt = sqlsrv_query($conn, $clientInfo);

echo "<div style='width: 100%; display: inline-block;'>";

while ($client = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC))
{
    echo "<div class='clientid' style='height: 50px; font-size: 18px; vertical-align: middle; display: inline-block; width: 100%'>" . 

            "
            <div style='width: 35%;'></div>

            <div onclick=\"voteUp()\" style='display: inline-block; width: 5%;'>      
                <span style='font-size: 20px;' class='hover-cursor fa fa-chevron-up vote-up'></span>
            </div>" .

                 "<div class='hover-cursor hvr-underline-reveal' style='width: 20%; display: inline-block;' data-clientid='{$client['ClientID']}'>" . $client['Client'] . "</div>" . 

            "<div onclick=\"voteDown()\" style='display: inline-block; width: 5%;'>
                <span style='font-size: 20px; text-align: right;' class='hover-cursor fa fa-chevron-down vote-down'></span>
            </div>

            <div style='width: 35%;'></div>

         </div> 
        <br />";
}

echo "</div>";

?>
```

as you see above there is an onclick for voteUp() function.

At the bottom of my page i have

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/scripts.js"></script>
```

and in **scripts.js** (I got the bit for voteUp() from a tutorial on clicking a div to run a php file)

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('.pull-me').click(function()
    {
        $('.panel1').slideToggle('fast')
    });
    $('.pull-me').click(function()
    {
        $('.panel2').slideToggle('fast')
    });
    $('.pull-me').click(function()
    {
        $('.panel3').slideToggle('fast')
    });

    $("#selection-box1").change(function()
    {
        document.location.href = $(this).val();
    });

    $(".output").click(function () 
    {
        var noteid = $(this).data("noteid");
        var templatenoteid = $(this).data("templatenoteid");
        var variablenoteid = $(this).data("variablenoteid");

        if ($(this).data("noteid")) 
        {
            $("#right-box").load("noteContent.php", {noteid: noteid});
        }

        else if ($(this).data("templatenoteid")) 
        {
            $("#right-box").load("templateNoteContent.php", {templatenoteid: templatenoteid});
        }

        else
        {
            $("#right-box").load("variableContent.php", {variablenoteid: variablenoteid});
        }
    });


    var modal = document.getElementById('login-box');

    window.onclick = function(event)
    {
        if (event.target == modal) 
        {
            modal.style.display = "none";
        }
    }

    //This script votes up and down for the client

    function voteUp()
    {
        $.get("voteup.php");
        return false;
    }

    function voteDown()
    {
        $.get("votedown.php");
        return false;
    }

});
```

And Finally in **voteup.php**

```
<?php include 'connectionDetails.php'; ?>

<?php

if (isset($_POST['clientid'])) 
{
    $voteup = "UPDATE Clients SET Pos = (SELECT MAX(Pos) FROM Clients) + 1 WHERE ClientID = " . $_POST['clientid'];

    $stmt = sqlsrv_query($conn, $voteup);
}
else
{
    echo "No ClientID";
}

?>
```

When i click on the Vote Up Button which is the DIV with onclick ="voteUp()"

**Why do i get an error in the console saying "ReferenceError: voteUp is not defined"**

Comment: Are you including the script properly?

Comment: my whole display page (clients.php) http://pastebin.com/Zk5TPxb3
but yes, the folders and location is correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have scoped out the methods.

Instead you can attach them to windows to be accessible from any place.

```
window.voteUp  = function()
{
    $.get("voteup.php");
    return false;
}

window.voteDown = function()
{
    $.get("votedown.php");
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Hi this fixed my error so i will vote as the answer, but i was just wondering why not nothing happens at all, when i check my database the column value is still the same, the error is gone and the only feedback from the console is the "GET xhr "voteup.php" but its not hitting my query for some reason

Comment: Because you are sending the $.get call. It needs to be $.post call and with data such as client_id because you are using `if (isset($_POST['clientid'])) `

Answer (score 0):

> Why do I get an error in the console saying "ReferenceError: voteUp is not defined"

Scope.

The `voteUp()` and `voteDown` are defined in the startup block (within the `{}` of `$(document).ready(function() ...` so are not available outside this block.

You need to move the two functions outside:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    ...
});

function voteUp()
{
    $.get("voteup.php");
    return false;
}

function voteDown()
{
    $.get("votedown.php");
    return false;
}
```

Comment: @JayBlanchard I'm not sure the relevance of that question.  Document ready is for initialising events etc once the the DOM is ready; it's not for defining reusable functions as is the case here.

Comment: @JayBlanchard And this is exactly the same as the (later) accepted answer.  I'm confused by your comment.

Comment: @JayBlanchard I'm surprised you're saying that.  Functions declared inside a function() block are scoped to that function block.  They can't be called from outside that function block.  They can be called from events defined in that function block, but that's not the case here (but would be in your valid recommendation to refactor how the event is declared).   Example: https://jsfiddle.net/dqxcw95t/  (check console)

Comment: It's all about scope. Inline JS calls are for functions in the global scope. Perhaps my previous comment was not worded well. What I was trying to say is that reusable functions can be defined *anywhere* but you must call them properly or namespace them properly in order to avoid scope issues.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use jQuery instead of inline JS? Give your div's classes:

```
<div class="voteup" data-clientid="{$client['ClientID']}">...</div>
```

Then use jQuery instead of `onclick()` as it would be much cleaner:

```
$(document).on('click', '.voteup', function(){
    var clientid = $(this).data('clientid');
    $.get("voteup.php", { clientid: clientid });
    return false;
})
```

Since you're already using jQuery this will help you to keep your markup cleaner, giving you the freedom to make changes much more easily to your markup and your JavaScript.

In addition, this will remove scoping issues so that you do not have to add namespaces.

The only other problem I see is that you're not passing `$_POST['clientid']` to voteup.php, so your query will never run. You can include `data-client-id` in your `div` declaration but you will have to change your test in your PHP to be:

```
if (isset($_GET['clientid']))
```

As you would be sending the value along wwith a GET request.